# Why PCA gives vector as output for 294*40 matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation, pca

I am new to stats and matlab too.
I have to do feature selection in my project so I used principle component analysis(pca).

I referred [tutorial to use pca in matlab](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html)

My code is given below,

```
 pcaInput = rand(294,40);
 disp(size(pcaInput))     % output is 294 40


 pcaOutput=pca(pcaInput);
 disp(size(pcaOutput))    % output is 40 1 , Unacceptable as per tutorial
 %that's it
```

As per the tutorial , if the input matrix of pca() function has p variables , then the output is p*p matrix.So the function should give me a matrix of 40*40 but it is giving me a matrix of 40*1. where I am going wrong ?

As per the tutorial , this output is unacceptable. I searched on the internet for that but , can not find any article on this topic.

[image]

Comment: I got a size of `40 x 40`.  You should probably double check your work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue using your sample there...I am also getting the correct result of `40 40`.

Comment: @rayryeng I did it thrice.... please check edits

Comment: @rayryeng is there problem with my matlab ?

Comment: @user2670535 - You most likely are using an older version of MATLAB.  I'm using R2013a.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @user2670535 , MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a) I am using

Comment: can linux creates problem with matlab sometimes ?

Comment: @user2670535 - I'm not sure... You're using a newer version than I am yet we are getting different results... with documentation that is for R2015a lol.  I can't comment any further.  Let's wait and see if anyone else can produce your results.

Comment: I use Matlab 2014a like you, and `pcaOutput` is 40x40. Try to open `pca` (right click on `pca`, then `Open "pca"` in the contextual menu), and show what you get.

Comment: something is going worst , I tried in Matlab R2013b in windows , but still getting the same problem. Is that qualitative data that is making pca()  to abnormal condition. I have a combination of qualitative and quantitative data as input.

Comment: @CTZStef It is showing me the same thing as in the webpage , that explains how to use pca() in matlab.